# Does a Salvadoran national need a transit visa to go through LHR airside on way to USA?

Tags: visas, transit, lhr, timatic, vie

I am traveling VIE-LHR-LAX and back later this year and want to clarify some things. I am a Salvadoran national (SLV) living in Austria with a valid residence permit. If I input this into the UK [Home Office visa check website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) it results that ***normally*** I would need a visa to transit though the UK, but I qualify under 2 exceptions (EEA common format residence permit and valid US visa) for transit without visa (see image).

I understand airlines usually use timatic for document checks at check-in, so I checked this same itinerary with a free Timaticweb2 trial and got that I need a transit visa for the UK and the exceptions are not listed (see 2nd image). BTW, the free [IATA travel centre resource](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) shows the correct data according to the UK Home Office website (see third image).

So my questions are:

- Why the discrepancy?
- Will the airline here in Austria not allow me to board due to incomplete timatic results?
- Can I contact UK Border Force via email (I can't find an address though) and will they be willing to clarify?

Edit: Including the document input below (note that those dates are fictitious lol)

[image: UK Visa Check]
[image: UK Transit Requirements]
[image: IATA Travel Centre]
[image: document input]

Comment: For completeness, is the trip booked as a single ticket (one PNR)?

Comment: @Traveller yes, single ticket

Comment: I input your journey into Timatic and it showed TWOV *is* allowed for a Salvadoran national resident in Austria

Comment: @Traveller thanks for that. I mean all the sources say it's allowed so I am not surprised. Why the discrepancy on what I see in Timaticweb2 and IATA Travel centre and what you saw? Is timaticweb2 not as close as to what airlines use as possible?

Comment: Are you sure you input both ‘Residence country: Austria’ *and* ‘Residency document: Residence Permit’ in Timatic? https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external-result/pFo0GnCWxzx3Z11OrhL4h58pRqOyTg

Comment: @Traveller I see the issue now, timaticweb2 only shows those exemptions when the transit is specifically set to LHR, not just UK. Thanks. Will close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed @Traveller 's finding that yes Salvadorans may transit without visa if they meet the criteria set out by the Home office in the images provided in the question.

The input into Timatic needs to be LHR as transit, not just United Kingdom:
[image: LHR Transit]

This results in the following output:
[image: Timatic Output]